# How can i find the default branch from a list of remote repos in python?

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I need to pass from the command line a list of repos and detect their default branches. So far i only found this command that returns the default HEAD `git remote show origin | grep 'HEAD' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g'`

However, i'm not sure how should i execute it in my code.

Here's the execution command python3 app.py testrepo.

And below is the code

```
@app.route('/test')
def get_default_branch():
    repos = sys.argv[1:]
    origin =repos[0]
    return subprocess.Popen([f"'git', 'remote', 'show', '{origin}''" + "| grep 'HEAD' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g''" ])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+get+output+subprocess

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the output, using the `check_output` api is probably easier

```py
@app.route('/test')
def get_default_branch():
    repos = sys.argv[1:]
    origin =repos[0]
    return subprocess.check_output(
        f"git remote show {origin} | grep 'HEAD' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g'",
        shell=True
    )
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Withh `shell=True` it is also recommended to use strings instead of a list